# Issue with Atop on Debian

Tags: debian, atop

I am having an issue with Atop installed on Debian Jessie which consumed a lot of disk.
After my investigation I found something:

1. Many log files not being compressed

There are many log files which are stored in */home/logs/atop/*, however they are not compressed as expected

```
[root@Ser1:~]# ll /home/logs/atop/ total 103796
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 406893656 Mar 10 12:57 atop_20171227
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 388460559 Mar 10 12:57 atop_20171228
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 389145084 Mar 10 12:57 atop_20171229
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 387274692 Mar 10 12:57 atop_20171230
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 379908323 Mar 10 12:57 atop_20171231
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 380787044 Mar 10 12:57 atop_20180101
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 373129068 Mar 10 12:57 atop_20180102
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 369377233 Mar 10 12:57 atop_20180103
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 362238156 Mar 10 12:57 atop_20180104
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 367661191 Mar 10 12:57 atop_20180105
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 355644913 Mar 10 12:57 atop_20180106
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 350190636 Mar 10 12:57 atop_20180107
```

2. Strange process

When I checked on the current processing with `ps -ef | grep atop`, there are tons of things that are currently running, from very old time

```
[root@Ser1:~]# ps -ef | grep atop
root      1451     1  0 Jan05 ?        00:07:31 /usr/bin/atop -a -w /home/logs/atop/atop_20180105 300
root      1498     1  0 Jan05 ?        00:06:05 /usr/bin/atop -a -w /home/logs/atop/atop_20180105 300
root      3464     1  0 Jan01 ?        00:06:49 /usr/bin/atop -a -w /home/logs/atop/atop_20180101 300
root      3508     1  0 Jan01 ?        00:06:19 /usr/bin/atop -a -w /home/logs/atop/atop_20180101 300
root      3826     1  0 Feb21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/atop -a -w /home/logs/atop/atop_20180221 300
root      3886     1  0 Feb21 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/atop -a -w /home/logs/atop/atop_20180221 300
root      4005     1  0 Jan24 ?        00:03:42 /usr/bin/atop -a -w /home/logs/atop/atop_20180124 300
root      4051     1  0 Jan24 ?        00:03:41 /usr/bin/atop -a -w /home/logs/atop/atop_20180124 300
root      4117     1  0 Feb17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/atop -a -w /home/logs/atop/atop_20180217 300
root      4155     1  0 Feb17 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/atop -a -w /home/logs/atop/atop_20180217 300
root      4189     1  0 Feb13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/atop -a -w /home/logs/atop/atop_20180213 300
root      4236     1  0 Feb13 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/atop -a -w /home/logs/atop/atop_20180213 300
root      4339     1  0 Mar05 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/atop -a -w /home/logs/atop/atop_20180305 300
```

So this makes me wonder if this atop is hang somehow?

3. ATOP is not running when I run command *[root@Ser1:~]# atop*

Moreover, when I wanted to check atop config files (which should be the file which indicate how the atop logs are store like *atop.daily* in Centos) I have no way to find it in Debian.

Could you please help me on this matter?
How to make Atop stop running such many of "hang" processes like that and how to make the log rotated?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this issue and this was successful

This issue was caused by hung processes of atop, then i tried with killing one by one of these processes with `kill -9 'PID'` then restarted the service and it runs as expected
Now new raw log files are created with corresponding date and I can run atop command to monitor server's stats

Thanks,